# navigator.onLine always True on localhost?

Tags: html

How to set `navigator.onLine` to know that i stopped the local server, it only listens for Wifi or Wire connection, and cant detect the **Local Server** state.

Comment: I think it means whether the network is up, not whether the target server is listening, so it's not the same thing. You could send ping-type requests to your server and see if any time out? And why would you to stop the server and test this anyway?

Comment: Can't you detect localhost via the page URL (`location.href`)? Fore instance, my own locally hosted sites have `.loc` top level domains.

Comment: @Rup this is for testing purpose, to see how my application can behave when the server is not responding (offline mode)
@ŠimeVidas dont undersand? i just run them as `localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the value of `navigator.onLine` is actually up to the browser. For example, in case of IE it would return it's status (whether it's in offline mode or not). It won't return a value based on server availability or anything like that, because by default the Connection to the server will be closed once the data transfer is done.

If you want your web page to know whether the server can still be reached you should opt for some Ajax request happening in background. If it timeouts, the server is gone (disconnected, bad network connection, etc.).

Comment: so the `navigator.onLine` will see what is up to `loopback` and not what is down? (layer)

Comment: No, it most likely won't check your (server) connectivity at all. It just returns the generic status of the browser ("Is it running in offline mode?" rather than "Can it reach the internet?").